# Is there a M1A1 carbine replica production?

Tags: guns, rifles

I've always wanted to have an M1A1 carbine. However, I don't want an "original" one because I think that this would be too valuable in my hands. I don't want to take one away from a real collector.

That's why I need to know if there are still any replicas in production?

Comment: A quick Google search has pulled up quite a few of them from several different sites, around $250.  There were also a few entries on GunBrokers.com, but I didn't look at the prices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 different manufacturers currently making these.

- [Auto Ordance](https://www.auto-ordnance.com/auto-ordnance-m1-carbine/)
- [Inland Manufacturing](https://www.inland-mfg.com/Inland-Carbines/M1-1945.html)
- [Fulton Armory](https://www.fulton-armory.com/M1-Carbine.aspx)

There is also [a stock](https://www.eabco.net/M1-Carbine-Replica-Ruger-1022-Stock-and-Tribute-Version-20--Includes-TWO-Handguards_p_13774.html) for 10-22 rifles that make it look like an m1 carbine but still fires 22 ammo.

Of course, you can also still buy the originals.